# How start an IBAction by dragging on a UIButton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I need help with my `iPhone` application. I currently have 5 `UIButtons` in a view linked with different `IBActions`. The buttons are placed one close to each other. I would like to know how to make the user able to press **all the buttons** just by dragging his finger on the buttons instead of pulling the finger away from the screen of his device and tap on a different button.

If you can't understand how the buttons are placed here's a picture ^.^

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each of the buttons, you could set the `Touch Drag Outside` event AND the `Touch Drag Enter` button event from the **Connections Inspector** to call the appropriate IBAction, so that the method is called when any one of them is touched and while the finger is still dragging toward the others. It may require two events for every button, depending on what exact behaviour you're looking for.

Remember that although it may deviate from the Model-View-Controller (MVC) way of doing things, one can set an IB element to call multiple IBActions and multiple events can be used to call the same IBAction.

The events will be listed in the connection inspector after you select each button. Press CMD+2 to jump to the connection inspector tab.

Comment: Thanks. But am I able to set two events for a single button? Mhmm need to try it ^.^ I'll let you know

Comment: Yes, I actually just made an edit to this answer to that effect. ;)

Comment: Mapping another connection does not supplant a previous one. So that will help in your current case. But be careful in the future to remember to break unwanted connections, as they don't break on their own.

Comment: OK. I tried setting Touch Drag Outside and Enter but the action it's repetitive and, because all IBAction plays a different sound file with AVAudioPlayer, the sound is repetitive too :C. Is there an other way to do it?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're wanting a different sound to play for each button, whenever the user drags their finger over one or more buttons? There are many ways to skin a cat. Just depends on the cat.

Comment: Also, do you have separate methods for each of these or are you using the button IDs as a parameter to differentiate between them?

Comment: Yes, each button plays a different sound and every button has a dedicated IBAction. To explain better, referring to the image, the user must be able to press button 1 and press button 2 by dragging his finger from number one to number two, without removing the finger from the screen. I know it's a bit complicated but thanks for your help!

Comment: it just does not work like that. It behaves as follows: touch drag and re-enter the same button, not drag on any other button. At least in my case. Very misleading name of the action in XCode's IB.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose one option would be to use the TouchesXX event(s).  For instance you could pick up on touches dragged and in code you could fire the button event handlers (the IBActions).  Of course you would have to know the locations of the other buttons to determine if they have been dragged over.  I'm not sure if that is what you are looking for but that would be one option.